# What server name and postURL do I upload data to? -Xcode to mySQL database

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I am extremely confused as to what to put in my PHP file for DB Host Name, as well as the URL I should post the data to.  I am building an iOS app that sends data to a mySQL database hosted on arvixe.com.  For my db host name, arvixe support said the server name is "dunlin.arvixe.com".  However, on phpMyAdmin the server name shows "localhost:3306".  I have also been told that I can simply use my domain name which is "aerodial.com".  I'm wondering what exactly do I put for the database server name in my PHP file, and also what URL do I insert the data into from Xcode?

I have posted my PHP file and the postURL code in Xcode to help clarify.  Sorry for the confusing noob question, but would appreciate any help!

```
<?php
    $username = “aerodial_dbuser”;
    $database = “aerodial_database”;
    $password = “********”;

    mysql_connect(dunlin.arvixe.com, $username, $password); <--WHAT SERVER NAME TO USE HERE?

    @mysql_select_db($database) or die(“Unable to find database”);

    $cityName = $_GET[“cityName”];

    $details = $_GET[“details”];

    $query = “INSERT INTO test VALUES (‘’, ‘$cityName’, ‘$details’)”;

    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error(“error”));

    mysql_close();

?>
```

Xcode post URL definition

```
#define kPostURL @"http://aerodial.com/tutorial.php"<--WHAT URL TO USE HERE?
#define kcityName @"cityName"
#define kDetails @"details"
```

Methods:

```
-(void) postMessage:(NSString*) details withName:(NSString*)cityName{

if (cityName != nil && details != nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString          stringWithString:kPostURL];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kcityName, cityName]];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kDetails, details]];

    [postString setString:[postString    stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:postString]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


  }


}

-(IBAction)post:(id)sender{


[self postMessage:_detailsField.text withName:_cityField.text];



_detailsField.text = @"";

_parkField.text = @"";

_cityField.text =@"";
```

}

Comment: I understand that mysql_connect is deprecated but for now I would just like to figure out the server name as well as what URL I need to upload my data to?

Comment: What URL do you use to upload your PHP and to view your pages?

Comment: Mysql functions are now depreciated consider using PDO or mysqli

Comment: To upload my PHP I do it under File Manager in myPHP admin under the public_html option.  The url is https://aerodial.com:2083/cpsess1373047773/frontend/x3/filemanager/dir.html?dir=%2fhome%2faerodial%2fpublic_html

Comment: When I upload my PHP file, it shows it is uploading to "/home/aerodial/public_html"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the information your host service provided you is correct, `dunlin.arvixe.com` is the correct name for your data server. phpMyAdmin is showing the server name as `localhost` because phpMyAdmin is running on a web server *on the same box* as the database.

You will presumably be accessing your web applications through the domain name `aerodial.com`. You may need to add a port number to that, but that's a question between you and your host service.

Comment: Try aerodial.com/tutorial.php first. If there is a port number it most likely won't be 2083 because that leads to your cPanel login screen.

Comment: nothing is working for the URL  :/  I've been at this for weeks and can't get it figured out.  Really frustrating but I want to get it fixed.

Comment: Where is it going sideways for you? Is it on the client-to-app or the app-to-database?

Comment: It's app-to-database.  Nothing is showing up in my database. Pretty sure it's from a wrong postURL

Comment: Break it down. Bodge up a php app that queries the db and shows the results in the browser. If that works, try a "Hello, World" from the phone to the web server. Work on getting each step of the process working in isolation; once they're all working alone you can start plugging them together.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that.  As far as showing the results in the browser, how will I be able to view it if the browser doesn't show php? How would I go about parsing it to make sure it works correctly?  Right now, my domain.com/php file shows a white page in the browser which I am assuming means it's working correctly since there are no errors

Comment: PHP is most commonly used to generate HTML which is returned to the browser. Consult the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php); you'll find plenty of sample code.